# Why doesn't /tmp use tmpfs?

Tags: filesystem, tmpfs, tmp

I have loads of RAM and I use very little. I also do record some screencasts with `gtk-recordmydesktop`, which by default saves to `/tmp` while recording. I assumed that it would mean storing to RAM as much as possible, but then I actually checked and found that `/tmp` isn't mounted with tmpfs. Why is that?

Comment: See [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/livecd-rootfs/+bug/1533639).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you answered your own question. A lot of programs use `/tmp` for storing temporary files, and they can be huge.

For example *Brasero* defaults to that directory to store a CD/DVD's image file, which can be 4.7 GB of size. It's not worth risking a serious slowdown (or a system lockup) in an **out of memory** situation if your RAM and swap get full.

For advanced users it's no problem to change some applications' defaults and mount `/tmp` as `tmpfs`. For general use it's just not worth the risk I guess.

Comment: And, I think you might get a little angry and curse the developers if you recorded a few great screencasts and then, after a power outage or system hitch, lost them all. ;)

Comment: And the stuff in /tmp might even reside in the RAM and never touch the disk if you use ext4.

Comment: @Fraekkert: What do you mean? Why ext4? Why never? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: It's not unique to ext4, but it's because of **Delayed allocation**. Essentially it means that files are not necessarily written to disk just because a program tells the os to do so. Instead it is kept in the ram for quick access. If the file is deleted relatively quickly thereafter, it would never reach the disk. Have a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) if you need more info.

Comment: @Fraekkert: I think the commit time is 5 secs for ext4, and the allocation is delayed until next commit, so it doesn't help much in this case, does it?

Comment: Hmm, generally speaking, under ext4 it is 30 seconds, not 5. So if you remove the file within 30 secs, it might not be actually written out to disk. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: For reference, here is a comment explaining the 5/30 seconds topic in detail: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/317781/comments/45

Answer (score 11):

What about zram compression ?

The available space is more than 256 Mbytes, it depends on files' type.

```
modprobe zram num_devices=1 
# max ram usage = 256 Mbytes
echo 262144 > /sys/block/zram0/disksize
mke2fs -q -m 0 -b 4096 -O sparse_super -L zram /dev/zram0
mount -o relatime,noexec,nosuid /dev/zram0 /tmp
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty interesting idea...will try this out :)

Answer (score 8):

There was an idea to use tmpfs while it has enough space, and write to disk when you run out of space: http://www.bigdbahead.com/?p=137
However, it never really took off.
I've managed to get it working, but the FUSE overhead defeats any benefit of using tmpfs: http://shnatsel.blogspot.com/2011/11/miniwheatfs-aka-reliable-ramdisks.html