# What are relevant disk benchmark settings for a desktop system

Tags: performance, disk, disk-usage

**NOTE:** This is not a question about which tools to use to fine tune disks.

---

I am about to replace an HD with an SSD and also to fine tune some of the disk settings. Also, I might distribute my filespace around the SSD and HD according to space and use. What are the relevant benchmarks (e.g. of the kind that [bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/) provides) that one needs to keep an eye on. Also, what pitfall might there be when testing them on HD and SSD?

Typical use will be for a desktop system: office type work, compiling some source, maybe iterating through a collection of large files for some data analysis, web browsing.

**EDIT:** I maintain that this is not a duplicate of ["How to check hard disk performance"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance). I am not interested in the kind of tools that will perform benchmarking but rather what the benchmarks are that are important for a particular user profile (a desktop user). I know that bonnie++, hdparm, and (with care) dd can all give me some idea of how quickly data can move to and from the disks. That in itself does not answer which of the many parameters offered is of importance when tuning a desktop system.

Comment: to measure a harddisk with benchmark-programs is "stress" for harddisk - so be cautious if you have new ssd - don't stress it too much with benchmarking. it would be a pity.
less benchmarking can make life of harddisks twice or triple longer ...

Comment: @dschinn1001 that's totally not true. It is true that benchmarking is a stress test, but taking twice or 3 times the time a hard drive lasts is really out there. I would say it would simply take an hour tops from an average of 5 years..