# Check disk benchmark result with the disk running the OS

Tags: 13.10, disk

Is there a way to check my disks benchmark results that's currently running the Ubuntu I'm on? Or do I have to unplug the disk and check it in another computer?

Answer (score 1):

In order to benchmark a disk it is best to insure it is unmounted (both for accurate results and safety). I usually use the disks utility for this in 12.04, 14.04 and 16.04 but that utility seems buggy in 13.xx. There are a number of other good suggestions for benchmarking found here: [How to check hard disk performance](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87035/how-to-check-hard-disk-performance)