# Slow speed while transferring files from pc to USB Hard drive

Tags: usb-drive

Since I upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 I'm suffering of slow speed while transfer files from my computer to my USB Hard Drive, like 28 hours for 500 GB. Any idea why? Thanks in advice

Comment: filesystem on your HDD?

Comment: NTFS, I tried and format to ext4 but i can't copy files

Comment: When transferring files from the HDD to PC the speed is ok

Comment: check this out: http://askubuntu.com/a/87036/222026