# Live usb does not recognize SSD: should I use AHCI/NVMe?

Tags: system-installation, ssd, raid, nvme

I just received a new Dell Latitude E5440 running Windows 11. I'm trying to install Ubuntu but since I'm doing this once every ten years I got a new problem every decade. My problem is Ubuntu, on live USB does not recognize the SDD of the laptop.

I fixed the problem myself in the BIOS by disabling RAID. Instead, I checked AHCI/NVMe.

I have a very blur idea of what is RAID. I don't know what is AHCI/NVMe. I have 3 options is the BIOS in the "SATA/NVMe Operations" panel:

1. Disabled
2. AHCI/NVMe
3. RAID on

Since RAID is not working, it remains 1 and 2. Which one should I use ? AHCI/NVMe is working by the way, the disk is recognized by the live usb.

Comment: Try just benchmarking it. NVMe was designed to be faster than SSDs than SATA, but I don't know why it's in a menu with RAID. Test linear/random-access sequential/parallel reads/writes to see what works best on this hardware

Comment: How I am supposed to test that ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/87036/1004020 should either be enough or a good start

Comment: The Windows "Fast Boot" setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: @waltinator My plan is to erase and format the entire disk during the installation. I do not plan to boot on windows even once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since RAID is not working, it remains 1 and 2. Which one should I use ? AHCI/NVMe is working by the way, the disk is recognized by the live usb.

The fact that it works is basically giving you the answer.

AHCI/NVMe is the native interface for SATA/NVMe devices, and probably what will give you best performance. Simply leave it there.

Comment: Actually I tested the option 1 "disabled" and the disk is not recognized either.

Comment: My guess is that *Disabled* actually means the interface is disabled.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. You clarified my misconception that the first "Disabled" option would enable SATA/AHCI emulation and the second option would enable the recommended NVMe

Comment: My guess is that SATA/NVMe is decided based on what the drive supports.