# Installing Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop into new desktop nvdia computer

Tags: boot, usb, 22.04, nvidia-geforce

I downloaded the .iso file and created a bootable usb with Ventoy.

This is what I got after booting the usb and selecting "Try or Install Ubuntu". It got stuck here for a few minutes, so I had to press and hold the power button of my PC to close.

[image]

secure boot and fast boot is disabled btw
Also tried to setup the usb stick with balenaEtcher as well as rufus, but it did not help

And I tried to run the Ubuntu safe graphics option and it works then even though the screen is scuffed. (i can't see the whole window)

afaik I need to install Nvidia drivers i guess before/during/after installation somehow but I don't know how.

My Nvida is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060

thank you

Comment: Go through the safe graphics option, and install to disk. Then install the Nvidia driver later by following https://askubuntu.com/a/1258909/1004020

Comment: @DanielT I installed through the safe graphics option. I chose "install alongside of windows boot manager", and selected basic install and checked third party software install option too when installing.

Comment: @DanielT after it told me to remove the installation medium and press enter, i did that. then on boot, i chose ubuntu. and this is what i got;

Comment: Oh, if you can't boot after install, then you need to temporarily enable safe graphics (nomodeset) after boot so that you can install the nvidia driver: https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/1004020

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/83wvsiX

@DanielT sorry for the multiple responses enter key automatically sends it it seems

Comment: @guiverc sorry im new. i don't know how much and what to say really. im adding it to the original post

Comment: That new picture suggests a SSD problem. Go into BIOS and try changing the NVMe/SATA options (https://askubuntu.com/q/1502099/1004020). If that still doesn't work, install a newer version of Ubuntu like 23.10

Comment: @DanielT Actually with nodemoeset it worked. I didn't do the last NVMe/SATA thing you suggested. With nodemodeset, Ubuntu started sucessfully. I'm writing this reply from Ubuntu :D Though i'm wondering, in the first link you shared `prime-select query` returns `on-demand` does that mean i'm good? I mean the resolution of the pc got better after installing the driver so i'm assuming everything is okay?

Comment: Yes, on-demand is OK. on-demand will intelligently choose to use your Intel iGPU for office work and your Nvidia GPU for gaming. The resolution improving means the Nvidia driver installed and loaded successfully! You're good, so I will try to close this as duplicate

Comment: @DanielT Definitely not. I looked into all of those before asking this question. Also i installed Ubuntu after you told me to do with safe graphics. I before looked to see if it was okay to install through Safe Graphics  but there were no answers or posts, they were for ubuntu 20 or 18.

I wish to answer my question by describing what i've done so far if that's okay in an hour or two.

thank you for everything btw

Comment: Ok, I retracted my flag so that you can self-answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue. Here's how;

First of all, there isn't a definitive answer saying if it's okay or not to install Ubuntu 22.04 through Safe Graphics option. And just turned out, it's fine to do so. But know that, afterwards, you'll need to `nomodeset` to be able to boot (until you install the Nvidia driver). (described below)

So i installed Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop with;

- Alongside Windows Boot Manager (because i wanted dual boot and already had Windows installed on my disk)
- Basic Setup (includes media formats, office softwares, etc.)
- Checked the install third party software option.

After installation, i booted Ubuntu with `nomodeset`, refer to here for how;
[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu/38834#38834) (But only difference is i didn't open up the grub boot screen as described. I simply selected a boot device, and chose `Ubuntu` that i just had installed)

After booting Ubuntu, i installed my Nvdia driver following here;
[How do I know which NVIDIA driver I need?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258904/how-do-i-know-which-nvidia-driver-i-need/1258909#1258909) (Basically i ran this then restarted my pc that's all;
`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`)

And that's all.

Thanks @DanielT for his big help along with his other big things <3

One extra thing is i don't know if matters or not but with Rufus and balenaEtcher i was getting `grub_platform command not found` error on grub boot screen. With Ventoy, i didn't have that so i recommend Ventoy to setup your USB.