# nvme device not ready aborting installation Busybox/Initramfs error when booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, initramfs, windows-11

In my computer, i first installed Windows 11. And then Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop.

The problem is, most of the time when i try to boot Ubuntu, i get the `nvme device not ready, aborting installation` error. And then it drops to BusyBox/initramfs. Sometimes when i wait about 20 seconds in the GRUB boot screen, Ubuntu opens up, sometimes (and most times) it doesn't.

Here's the picture of the error;
[image: picture of the error]

I did some Google'ing but all the related conversations are at least 7 years old and most of them require me to change stuff in BIOS which i'm hesitant to. And since sometimes Ubuntu just boots sucessfully, i'm not sure if i need to do that.

Thank you

Comment: What are the differences between this question and your previous https://askubuntu.com/q/1502400/1004020 ?

Comment: Even new system or NVMe drive may need firmware update. Check firmware versions & update from vendors support page if required. `udisksctl status`  & 
`inxi -d`  and `sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 5 "*-firmware"`

Comment: @DanielT My previous question was for my NVIDIA driver card installation and not being able to boot Ubuntu because of my graphics card. This question is me not being able to boot because of my SSD.

Comment: @ZekiKral Have you tried the `rootdelay=` kernel command line parameter?

Comment: @DanielT I wanted to but couldn't figure out how. Am i supposed to add that to the grub thing as in this picture; https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnUQa.png --- and how am i supposed to add it? --- And i'm hesitant about changing my bios settings or the software(firmware) of my ssd because i feel like i might lost some data. Because i read that for instance RAID type combines a few ssds and stuff and others dont and some types migt lose some data or something. And since it actually works currently i don't wanna change anything. The issue is before booting ubuntu i need to wait 20 seconds in the boot

Comment: screen. And even then it sometimes fail, saying nvme is not ready. I just keep trying a few more times and eventually it works.

Comment: You could also try the `rootwait` parameter. You add it to the screen in your picture to apply it for only one boot, and inside the "quite splash" in `/etc/default/grub` then `update-grub` for future boots. Another option that I am exploring in a similar question https://askubuntu.com/q/1503251/1004020 is to move GRUB to USB

Comment: to test the rootwait and rootdelay parameters, in the picture, can i add this at most top;
rootdelay=20
or
rootwait=20 also, i wrote 20 but is that in seconds, what the value should be you think? @DanielT

Comment: `rootwait` is argumentless. Idk, 20 seconds sounds a bit high for practical use, but is useful for testing

Comment: @DanielT hey man, since you told me to use rootwait, i've been using it like this (there is not an underscore after rootwait that's just the cursor);
https://imgur.com/a/kY8NYtO
And since  then, everytime i booted ubuntu, it booted properly. i don't even know if i'm using the rootwait correctly or not or just getting lucky but so far its working :D

Comment: @DanielT yeah that's same issue as me. So far rootwait is working for me i guess. I didn't edit any files because i just dont wanna deal with it. i just add the rootwait thing as i've shown and thats it. workign so far i guess or i'm getting very lucky and its just booting. thank you

Comment: Please accept the duplicate so that we can close the question